# How to modify the xml file with php

Tags: php

I am trying to update the XML file with the help of php. I am not able to find out, how to update the xml file using php. I created two input box, in which i am passing the value with form element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventors>
 <person>
 <name>anie</name>
 <comment>good</comment>
 </person>
</inventors>
```

And here is my php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true; 
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('sample.xml');

 //Get item Element
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('person')->item(0);  

 //Load child elements
 $name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
 $comment = $element->getElementsByTagName('comment')->item(0) ;

 //Replace old elements with new
 $element->replaceChild($name, $name);
 $element->replaceChild($comment, $comment);
 ?>

 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$name->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];
$comment->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];
htmlentities($xml->save('ak.xml'));

 }

 ?>

 <form method="POST" action=''>
  name <input type="text-name" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue  ?>" name="namanya" />
comment  <input type="text-comment" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue  ?>"  name="commentnya"/>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good story.  Where is your code broken?

Comment: @mickmackusa i don't know, but its not saving new values in xml file

Comment: `$element->replaceChild($name, $name);` does nothing. Also you need to specify form `action`, and made all the replacements there, in a separate file.

Comment: So whenever your scripts break, instead of trying to diagnose, research, and debug the issue, you think it is best to just post a question here?

Comment: @freeek do i need to create new xml file on every edit?

Comment: @ajaykumar no. Until **you** need this.

Comment: `htmlentities($xml->save('ak.xml'));` <-- this definitely doesn't look right.

Comment: @mickmackusa , Bro almost, 7 hours happend, i can't find the solution, tried everything to diagnose

Answer (score 1):

Right now your are trying to mix view and model.

You need to specify form's `action`:

```html
<form method="POST" action="person.php">
  name <input type="text-name" value="" name="namanya" />
  comment  <input type="text-comment" value=""  name="commentnya"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

And in your `pearson.php` do the change, something like:

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->formatOutput = true; 
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->load('sample.xml');

    $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('person')->item(0);  
    $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue = $_POST['namanya'];
    $element->getElementsByTagName('comment')->item(0)->nodeValue = $_POST['commentnya'];

    $xml->save('sample.xml'); // You have ak.xml here, but you wanted to update existing
}
```

If you need a new file, then don't replace some sample - just create a new `XML` structure.